# Saving a form .ui file with relative path?

Tags: qgis-2, forms

My company uses QGIS 2.18 (soon to upgrade to 3.4) and I've designed a form to make data entry for our survey field staff a little less hateful.

The .ui file is saved on a network drive, and as long as our field staff have access to the network, the form appears when they're doing data entry. However, sometimes they're working pretty remotely, with no access to a network (or the internet at all) and so the form no longer appears.

Is there a way to set up the .ui file so that it can be copied along with the other shapefile files to a users C:\ drive and have a relative path setting so that the .ui file will always be referenced no matter what folder the shapefile/ .ui file is saved in?

The workaround that I've thought about trying is to copy the .ui file to each users (around 15 ppl) computer and set up the shapefile .ui for each individual person, however this seems a bit cumbersome, will be prone to error, and just seems a bit inelegant.